# Trouble changing Meta TItle of CMS Page

Tags: layout, magento-1, xml, page-title, cms-pages

Im using this code in a CMS page under design> custom layout update XML

```
<reference name=”head”>
    <action method=”setForcedTitle”><title>Account Dashboard</title></action>
</reference>
```

When I try to update the page, I get this error

XML Data is Invalid.

Im using code from this guide.

http://www.harapartners.com/blog/complete-guide-title-tags-magento/

I have looked at several other sites to find out how to do this, and they all say to use this code.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I had to change out the page title in the html template from

```
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
```

to

```
<title><?php echo ($this->getForcedTitle()) ? $this->getForcedTitle() : $this->getTitle() ?></title>
```

Comment: good try .....but `getForcedTitle() ` will create exception error to most of pages bcoz rest of  pages we does not set getForcedTitle() value

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have using **magento 1.X Version**.

In default,magento *does not use have any function* name of **setForcedTitle**.

Or does not use  any setter function **setForcedTitle**,getter  function `getForcedTitle()`.

So,you does not use this function for set meta title.

If you want to change page title then you can set this from admin.

Just goto ***admin>CMS>Pages select your page> Page Information*** tab and under this tab on **Page Title**  field you can *set page title*.

Comment: What function would you use to set the meta title then?

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned that you are facing problem in magento 1.x or magento 2.0 ?

**For Magento 1.x**

In Magento 1.x just don't need and function to update CMS page meta, you can do it straight from admin panel

admin=>CMS=>Pages select your page=>Page Information=>Page Title

Through above path you can set meta title for CMS pages.

**For Magento 2.0**

admin=> Click Content to open the slide out menu=> Under Elements click Pages
(This is a list of all the content managed pages within your Magento 2.0)=> Click Select & then Edit to open the page you wish to add meta title=> This will open the Page Information=> add your meta title